# How to mimic Google Maps' bottom-sheet 3 phases behavior?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

### Background

I'm assigned to make a UI that behaves similarly to how Google Maps shows a bottom-sheet for a found result.

It has three different phases:

1. Bottom content. The upper area is still touchable and won't scroll anything at the bottom
2. Full-screen content, while the upper area has a large header.
3. Full-screen content, while the upper area has just the toolbar.

Here's what I'm talking about on Google Maps:

[image]

### The problem

Thing is, the bottom sheet isn't a part of the design library yet (though it was requested, [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179483)).

Not only that, but the UI seems quite complex and needs handling of the toolbar on multiple phases.

### What I've tried

I've found a good (enough) library for the bottom sheet ([**here**](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)), and added content to its fragment sample, to have about the same views as shown on material design samples (like [**here**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)), to have a CollapsingToolbarLayout that will take care of phases 2+3.

In the app I'm making, I also have to move an icon as you scroll, but I think that if I succeed with the rest, this should be easy.
Here's the code:

###fragment_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Related"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

###MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends BottomSheetFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        view.setMinimumHeight(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("AAA");
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
        });
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.cheese_1).centerCrop().into(imageView);
        return view;
    }
}
```

###BottomSheetFragmentActivity.java

```
public final class BottomSheetFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected BottomSheetLayout bottomSheetLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_sheet_fragment);
        bottomSheetLayout = (BottomSheetLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
        findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet_fragment_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MyFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.bottomsheet);
            }
        });
        bottomSheetLayout.setShouldDimContentView(false);
        bottomSheetLayout.setPeekOnDismiss(true);
        bottomSheetLayout.setPeekSheetTranslation(200);
        bottomSheetLayout.setInterceptContentTouch(false);
        bottomSheetLayout.setDefaultViewTransformer(new BaseViewTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformView(final float translation, final float maxTranslation, final float peekedTranslation, final BottomSheetLayout parent, final View view) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "translation:" + translation + " maxTranslation:" + maxTranslation + " peekedTranslation:" + peekedTranslation);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It almost works well. The only problem is the transition from #3 back to #2:

[image]

### The question

What is wrong with the code? What can I do in order to achieve the required behavior?

Comment: Look like Activity Transitions to me. Have you tried creating 2 Activities and applying material transitions between them ? And used `CoordinatorLayout` on the 2nd screen ?

Comment: @S.D. I'm very sure it's not 2 activities, because you can keep touching the screen to scroll and switch between the phases. It doesn't stop you to go to the next/previous activity. When opening a new activity, I don't think it's possible to persist the same touch events for the scrolling mechanism. I'm not even sure if it's possible using fragments, but this is probably more possible than activities.

Comment: Then I think all views are in same layout, with each having a specific [Behaviour](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) set on it. And all behaviours are being triggered from vertical scroll interception on root layout which co-ordinates everything.

Comment: @S.D. Do you know how to make it work well? Is it better than what I've found?

Comment: I think you should take a look at this [library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

Comment: @SaveliiZagurskii Did you try adding what I wrote into the sample of this library?

Answer (score 20):

**Note**: Read the edits at the bottom

---

OK, I've found a way to do it, but I had to change the code of multiple classes, so that the bottom sheet would know of the state of the appBarLayout (expanded or not), and ignore scroll-up in case it's not expanded:

#### BottomSheetLayout.java

Added fields:

```
private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
private OnOffsetChangedListener mOnOffsetChangedListener;
private int mAppBarLayoutOffset;
```

init() - added this:

```
    mOnOffsetChangedListener = new OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
            mAppBarLayoutOffset = verticalOffset;
        }
    };
```

Added function to set the appBarLayout:

```
public void setAppBarLayout(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
    if (mAppBarLayout == appBarLayout)
        return;
    if (mAppBarLayout != null)
        mAppBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
    mAppBarLayout = appBarLayout;
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
}
```

onDetachedFromWindow() - added this:

```
    if (mAppBarLayout != null)
        mAppBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
```

onTouchEvent() - added this:

```
      ...
      if (bottomSheetOwnsTouch) {
        if (state == State.EXPANDED && scrollingDown && mAppBarLayout != null && mAppBarLayoutOffset != 0) {
            event.offsetLocation(0, sheetTranslation - getHeight());
            getSheetView().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
      ...
```

Those were the main changes. Now for what sets them:

**MyFragment.java**

onCreateView() - added this:

```
    mBottomSheetLayout.setAppBarLayout((AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.appbar));
```

I also added this function:

```
 public void setBottomSheetLayout(final BottomSheetLayout bottomSheetLayout) {
    mBottomSheetLayout = bottomSheetLayout;
}
```

Now this is how the activity tells the fragment about the appBarLayout:

```
            final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            myFragment.setBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetLayout);
            myFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.bottomsheet);
```

The project is now available on GitHub:

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet

I hope it doesn't have any bugs.

---

The solution has bugs, sadly, so I won't mark this answer as the correct one:

1. It only works well on Android 6 and above. Others have a weird behavior of showing the bottom sheet expanded for a tiny fraction of a time, each time when showing it.
2. Orientation changes do not save the state of the scrolling at all, so I've disabled it.
3. Rare issue of being able to scroll inside the bottom sheet's content while it's still collapsed (at the bottom)
4. If a keyboard was shown before, the bottom sheet might get to be full screen when trying to peek.

If anyone can help with it, please do.

---

For issue #1, I've tried adding a fix by setting the visibility to INVISIBLE when the bottom sheet doesn't peek yet, but it doesn't always work, especially if a keyboard is shown.

---

For issue #1, I've found how to fix it, by just wrapping (in "fragment_my.xml") the CoordinatorLayout with any view that you wish to use (I used FrameLayout), and also put a full-sized view in it (I just put "View") , as such:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--This full sized view, together with the FrameLayout above, are used to handle some weird UI issues on pre-Android-6 -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <...CollapsingToolbarLayout 
    ...
```

It probably confused the bottomSheet when I had the CoordinatorLayout being its view.
I've updated the project, but still, if there is any way to have a nicer solution, I'd like to know about it.

---

In recent months, Google has published its own bottomSheet class, but as I've found it has a lot of issues, so I can't even try it out.

Comment: but what about this image? https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5357526/11641271/097c35d0-9d40-11e5-94c6-f9bef5f5ab9d.gif i want to implement this kind of image slide along with bottomsheet goes up

Comment: @HBdroid I think it's possible. maybe for the "onOffsetChanged" function, also change the translation of the mBottomSheetBackgroundImageView ? The requirement on my case were first to handle the 3 phases. Now it's a question of what to transition and how, and this is very customized and depends on your needs. It also requires a lot of annoying math. I suggest using instant-run feature to make it fast to try.

Comment: i am not able to find the solution please help me

Comment: @HBdroid Sorry I don't know. Try maybe removing this app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" . also try to do the translation in transformView .

Comment: @Hardy have you ended up creating the solution you wanted ? if yes is it open source and can it be shared ?

Comment: @NJay I know my answer is quite long, but the github repo is there... :) Here : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet

Comment: Thanks already got your code. cools really cool and appreciate you open sourcing it. Its a big buggy though. if you go from state 2 state changes it will not show the toolbar of the expanded view for example. I was just wondering if there was a ready stable solution before i end up using yours. @androiddeveloper

Comment: @NJay Yes I know. Sorry for that. If you know how to fix it, please let me know there.

Answer (score 16):

**BIG UPDATE**

Because there were like 4 or 5 questions about the same topic, BUT with DIFFERENT requirements, and I tried to answer all of them, but a non-polite admin deleted/closed them, making me create a ticket for each one and changing them to avoid "copy-paste" I will let you a link to the [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474350/1332549) in where you can find all the explanation about how to get full behavior like Google Maps.

---

Answering your question

> How to mimic Google Maps' bottom-sheet 3 phases behavior?

With support library 23.x.x+ you can do it by modifying the default `BottomSheetBehavior`, adding one more stat with the following steps:

1. Create a Java class and extend it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>`
2. Copy paste code from the default `BottomSheetBehavior`  file to your new one.
3. Modify the method `clampViewPositionVertical` with the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
       return constrain(top, mMinOffset, mHideable ? mParentHeight : mMaxOffset);
   }
   int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
       return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
   }
   ```
4. Add a new state:

   ```
   public static final int STATE_ANCHOR_POINT = X;
   ```
5. Modify the next methods: `onLayoutChild`, `onStopNestedScroll`, `BottomSheetBehavior<V> from(V view)` and `setState` (optional)

I'm going to add those modified methods and a [link to the example project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474350/1332549).

**And here is how its looks like** 
[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]

Comment: I've tested the github repo now, and it seems nice. But the upper blue area looks partial sometimes. Also, I can't find out where to handle views that need to move as you drag the bottom sheet. In the repo I've made (here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet) , the image fades, and the small image moves from one place to another, including changing its size. I'd like to know where to add the handling of those.

Comment: Hi there, I have a local version with parallax image but it is not working well yet (I can push it if u wanna look it). You can add any view inside the `CoordinatorLayout` in `activity_main.xml`. I guess you have good experience with coordinator layout, otherwise take a look at this [link that I found](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: I'm going to see how did you got toolbar behavior and will use it on mine :D. By the way there is a little behavior that I could only mimic if I use support library 23.2: in google maps if you drag the image that below the toolbar it will move the bottomsheet, but if you upgrade to 23.4 or minSdkVersion 14+ you will lose this behavior o_O'

Comment: @androiddeveloper I got it! now its working with image parallax effect and toolbars animations...I'm only missing the color that takes the toolbar when you keep sliding up :D

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC Hi, I want to only display main toolbar and i removed merged appbar layout but on bottom sheet expand time status bar not displaying and parallex image end to status bar position and i want to parallex image sticky below main toolbar. can you explain how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html?m=1
Here it says we can just specify a bottom sheet layout behavior.

**UPDATE:**

Basically, the link states-

By attaching a BottomSheetBehavior to a child View of a CoordinatorLayout (i.e., adding app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"), you’ll automatically get the appropriate touch detection to transition between five states:

```
STATE_COLLAPSED: this collapsed state is the default and shows just a portion of the layout along the bottom. The height can be controlled with the app:behavior_peekHeight attribute (defaults to 0)
STATE_DRAGGING: the intermediate state while the user is directly dragging the bottom sheet up or down
STATE_SETTLING: that brief time between when the View is released and settling into its final position
STATE_EXPANDED: the fully expanded state of the bottom sheet, where either the whole bottom sheet is visible (if its height is less than the containing CoordinatorLayout) or the entire CoordinatorLayout is filled
STATE_HIDDEN: disabled by default (and enabled with the app:behavior_hideable attribute), enabling this allows users to swipe down on the bottom sheet to completely hide the bottom sheet
Keep in mind that scrolling containers in your bottom sheet must support nested scrolling (for example, NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, or ListView/ScrollView on API 21+).
```

**If you’d like to receive callbacks of state changes, you can add a BottomSheetCallback:**

```
// The View with the BottomSheetBehavior  
 View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);  
 BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);  
 behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {  
    @Override  
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {  
      // React to state change  
    }  
      @Override  
      public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {  
       // React to dragging events  
   }  
 });
```

While BottomSheetBehavior captures the persistent bottom sheet case, this release also provides a BottomSheetDialog and BottomSheetDialogFragment to fill the modal bottom sheets use case. Simply replace AppCompatDialog or AppCompatDialogFragment with their bottom sheet equivalents to have your dialog styled as a bottom sheet.

Comment: The question was made before Google shown their support library class. If you have a working solution using it, please show it here.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I didn't read the date of question and hence I suggested this answer. But if you want to use this library you can use that. As far as the working solution for this code, I don't have it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to implement a view similar to how Google Maps shows a bottom-sheet for a found result.

Here's how mine looks:

[image: Peek view]

[image: Expand view scrolled to top]

[image: Expand view scrolled to bottom]

At first, I defined a bottom sheet with a header and scrollable content but the layout_height did not seem to wrap the content neither of the header nor the scrollable content despite specifying `wrap_content`.

That problem went away when I used `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` for the `CoordinatorLayout`'s child layout (and for its children).

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPeek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Peek"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonExpand"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonExpand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Expand"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonClose"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonPeek"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPeek" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonExpand"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonExpand" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator_child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFF0000"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerTextView_a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="a" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="c" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_d"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="d" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="e" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="f" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_g"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="g" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_h"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="h" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_i"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="i" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_j"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="j" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTextView_k"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="k" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet_scrollable_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FF00FF00"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet_scrollable_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView0"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="9" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="11" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="13" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="14" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="15" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="16" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="17" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="18" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="19" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="20" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView21"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="21" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView22"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="22" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView23"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="23" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView24"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="24" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView25"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="25" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView26"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="26" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView27"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="27" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView28"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="28" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView29"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="29" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView30"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="30" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView31"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="31" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView32"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="32" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView33"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="33" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView34"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="34" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView35"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="35" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView36"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="36" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView37"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="37" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView38"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="38" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView39"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="39" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView40"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView41"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView42"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="42" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView43"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="43" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView44"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="44" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView45"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="45" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView46"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="46" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView47"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="47" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView48"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="48" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView49"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="49" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bottomsheetwithscrollablecontent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CoordinatorLayout layout_coordinator;
    private View layout_coordinator_child;
    private View layout_bottom_sheet_header;

    private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout_coordinator = findViewById(R.id.layout_coordinator);
        layout_coordinator_child = layout_coordinator.findViewById(R.id.layout_coordinator_child);
        layout_bottom_sheet_header = layout_coordinator.findViewById(R.id.layout_bottom_sheet_header);

        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layout_coordinator_child);

        Button buttonPeek = findViewById(R.id.buttonPeek);
        buttonPeek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                behavior.setPeekHeight(layout_bottom_sheet_header.getHeight());
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        });

        Button buttonExpand = findViewById(R.id.buttonExpand);
        buttonExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });

        Button buttonClose = findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);
        buttonClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bottomsheetwithscrollablecontent"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04"
}
```