# Sliding BottomSheet like google map

Tags: android, google-maps, googleio

Currently i am using bottom sheet from [this lib](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet), I want to implement image  animation like this [google map](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5357526/11641271/097c35d0-9d40-11e5-94c6-f9bef5f5ab9d.gif)  while sliding of bottomsheet, i want to slide imageview along with it as per the image shown, 
I have already use this [link for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160423/how-to-mimic-google-maps-bottom-sheet-3-phases-behavior/34176633?noredirect=1#comment56361295_34176633) but not getting.
I have been trying so much hours on it but cant find any solution, Any help can be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, else no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I have just use this ThreePhasesBottomSheet lib and try to achieve this bt cant find any solution

Comment: I think this is what you want https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In past Google was not providing support of BottomSheet in its Design Library, But recently in its update API 23.2, google has revealed API for BottomSheet.

Check this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

**Update**

**Your Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <ImageView/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout>

            //.....

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        //your bottom sheet layout

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Your Java File**

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
// The View with the BottomSheetBehavior
View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        // React to state change
        Log.e("onStateChanged", "onStateChanged:" + newState);
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        // React to dragging events
        Log.e("onSlide", "onSlide");
    }
});

behavior.setPeekHeight(100);
```

Comment: Can you add a sniper of code in where we can see "the magic"? I mean, all answer in SO about this topic is about that link an no more... an answer far away from SO rulz....

Comment: Thx for that but if I understand well the question, he is asking about the image that appears when sliding up isn't? I mean you got how to show the official bottom sheet but nothing about the image xD

Comment: I didn't give the full answer, I just gave the way through that user can achieve what he want.

Answer (score 20):

You can do it **modifying** default `Behavior` for BottomSheet, ImageView, ToolBars and FAB.

First of all you need to add one more state to BottomSheetBehavior. You can do it with following steps:

1. Create a Java class and extend it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>`
2. Copy paste code from default `BottomSheetBehavior` file to your new one.
3. Modify the method `clampViewPositionVertical` with the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
       return constrain(top, mMinOffset, mHideable ? mParentHeight : mMaxOffset);
   }
   int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
   return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
   }
   ```
4. Add a new state

   ```
   public static final int STATE_ANCHOR_POINT = X;
   ```
5. Modify the next methods: `onLayoutChild`, `onStopNestedScroll`, `BottomSheetBehavior<V> from(V view)` and `setState` (optional)

I'm going to add those modified methods and a [link to the example project](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) in where you can see all Custom Behaviors

```
public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, int layoutDirection) {
    // First let the parent lay it out
    if (mState != STATE_DRAGGING && mState != STATE_SETTLING) {
        if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(parent) &&
                !ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(child)) {
            ViewCompat.setFitsSystemWindows(child, true);
        }
        parent.onLayoutChild(child, layoutDirection);
    }
    // Offset the bottom sheet
    mParentHeight = parent.getHeight();
    mMinOffset = Math.max(0, mParentHeight - child.getHeight());
    mMaxOffset = Math.max(mParentHeight - mPeekHeight, mMinOffset);

    //if (mState == STATE_EXPANDED) {
    //    ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMinOffset);
    //} else if (mHideable && mState == STATE_HIDDEN...
    if (mState == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mAnchorPoint);
    } else if (mState == STATE_EXPANDED) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMinOffset);
    } else if (mHideable && mState == STATE_HIDDEN) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mParentHeight);
    } else if (mState == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMaxOffset);
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper == null) {
        mViewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(parent, mDragCallback);
    }
    mViewRef = new WeakReference<>(child);
    mNestedScrollingChildRef = new WeakReference<>(findScrollingChild(child));
    return true;
}


public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target) {
    if (child.getTop() == mMinOffset) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
        return;
    }
    if (target != mNestedScrollingChildRef.get() || !mNestedScrolled) {
        return;
    }
    int top;
    int targetState;
    if (mLastNestedScrollDy > 0) {
        //top = mMinOffset;
        //targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (currentTop > mAnchorPoint) {
            top = mAnchorPoint;
            targetState = STATE_ANCHOR_POINT;
        }
        else {
            top = mMinOffset;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        }
    } else if (mHideable && shouldHide(child, getYVelocity())) {
        top = mParentHeight;
        targetState = STATE_HIDDEN;
    } else if (mLastNestedScrollDy == 0) {
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (Math.abs(currentTop - mMinOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - mMaxOffset)) {
            top = mMinOffset;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        } else {
            top = mMaxOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
    } else {
        //top = mMaxOffset;
        //targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (currentTop > mAnchorPoint) {
            top = mMaxOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
        else {
            top = mAnchorPoint;
            targetState = STATE_ANCHOR_POINT;
        }
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, targetState));
    } else {
        setStateInternal(targetState);
    }
    mNestedScrolled = false;
}

public final void setState(@State int state) {
    if (state == mState) {
        return;
    }
    if (mViewRef == null) {
        // The view is not laid out yet; modify mState and let onLayoutChild handle it later
        /**
         * New behavior (added: state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT ||)
         */
        if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED || state == STATE_EXPANDED ||
                state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT ||
                (mHideable && state == STATE_HIDDEN)) {
            mState = state;
        }
        return;
    }
    V child = mViewRef.get();
    if (child == null) {
        return;
    }
    int top;
    if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        top = mMaxOffset;
    } else if (state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT) {
        top = mAnchorPoint;
    } else if (state == STATE_EXPANDED) {
        top = mMinOffset;
    } else if (mHideable && state == STATE_HIDDEN) {
        top = mParentHeight;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal state argument: " + state);
    }
    setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, state));
    }
}


public static <V extends View> BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike<V> from(V view) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    if (!(params instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout");
    }
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) params)
            .getBehavior();
    if (!(behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike");
    }
    return (BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike<V>) behavior;
}
```

You can even use callbacks with `behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.BottomSheetCallback() {....`

**And here is how its looks like:**
[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]

Comment: Do you have a sample on github for this? :)

Comment: Yes @RoCk, there is a library [CustomBottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)