# Android Bottom Sheet from Android Design Support Library correct behavior

Tags: android, dialog, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to implement `BottomSheetDialog` from new Android Design Support Library 23.2.0. I have `layout` with `GoogleMap` `Fragment`, `Toolbar` and several fabs.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is next: when `BottomSheetDialog` is expanded  and I scroll `NestedScrollView` up, `BottomSheetDialog` doesn't collapse, it collapses only when I pull `AppBarLayout` of `BottomSheetDialog` down. I want to collapse `BottomSheetDialog` scrolling `NestedScrollView`.

**QUESTION #2**

How can I create `BottomSheetDialog` like this?

[image]

**MY CODE**

My `BottomSheetBehavior`:

```
View bottomSheet = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setUpMap() -> onStateChanged() -> newState: " + newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setUpMap() -> onSlide() -> slideOffset: " + slideOffset);
            }
        });

        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(100f, this));
```

My XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="ua.nau.edu.NAU_Guide.MapsActivity"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_maps" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/map"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorAppPrimary"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorAppPressed"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/colorAppRipped"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="1dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_route"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAppPrimary"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAppPressed"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAppRipped"
            fab:fab_shadowRadius="1dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAppPrimary"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAppPressed"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAppRipped"
            fab:fab_shadowRadius="1dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAppPrimary"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAppPressed"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAppRipped"
            fab:fab_shadowRadius="1dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/reveal_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/recyclerview_background"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_view_bsheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_drawer_primary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_bsheet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAppPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:contentScrim="@color/colorAppPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:title="">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/app_bar_bsheet_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                            android:paddingStart="24dp"
                            android:text="Bottom Sheet Title"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/app_bar_bsheet_subtitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                            android:paddingStart="24dp"
                            android:text="Bottom Sheet Subtitle"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_route_bsheet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_white_24dp"
                app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_bsheet"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
                app:useCompatPadding="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: About question 2, I don't think it is BottomSheetDialog , because BottomSheetDialog  blocks touch events outside of it. What you need is the normal bottomSheet instead. I've created a similar repo before the support library had bottomSheet: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet . Maybe it could help you? I plan on using the support library for this in the future. I've watched this video now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAgKp-BYv1I . Maybe this can help you ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, hi! Thank you for reply. I've created very similar BottomSheet with . It looks nice, but Google Map has gorgeous BottomSheet.

Comment: check this answer [Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310530/sliding-bottomsheet-like-google-map)