# Android Design like Google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, material-design

I am developing an application in which map is integrated and there are multi markers on it...
[image: Example]
As you seen in the picture I want to design my application like this...
Means in first the map markers are visible on the map. By clicking on it the bottom menu will appear as in the first screen in example picture...
Then if the user drag up this menu then the more detailed view will cover the half of the screen.
And by dragging up again then the full screen will cover up with activity or by fragment and the toolbar name is changed...
 As seen in the example picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mimic Google Maps' bottom-sheet 3 phases behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160423/how-to-mimic-google-maps-bottom-sheet-3-phases-behavior)

Comment: I am not able to find the the proper solution here....

Comment: you can't. still you can use bottom sheet check code https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet and https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

Comment: Thanks lemme try... Hope it will work...

Comment: @MoosaBaloch has anything changed since 1 year?? Were you able to implement the 3 phase behavior ?