# How to handle issues of the new bottom sheet of the support/design library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

### Background

I've used a modified version of [**bottom-sheet**](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) library ([**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ThreePhasesBottomSheet), based on [**this library**](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet), also wrote about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34160423/878126)), in order to have a nice transition between collapsed (AKA "peeked") state and expanded state.

The library had its issues, but in general, I've fixed them all.

### The problem

Recently we've found that after going back from all ad-networks screens, back to one that has a bottom sheet, the bottom sheet gets into a weird state of being expanded.

I've decided that it's time to try the new bottom-sheet of the support library (shown [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)), but I've found that it has a lot of basic related issues:

1. the bottom sheet gets shown right away, and in the wrong height.
2. it must have its height configured right away, without support for "wrap_content" and also can't have a height "match_parent" when expanded, as it will be on top of other views, including the toolbar.
3. When it's hidden, it still reacts to touch events and be shown again.
4. it will crash when I set its initial state.

And all this without even trying to handle what I wanted, which is the 3-phases I've done before.

### What I've tried

At first, I thought I just don't use the library well, so I've tried 2 samples I've found:

- https://github.com/vipulshah2010/BottomSheets
- https://github.com/chikkutechie/androidexamples

I also tried some code I've found here on StackOverflow, but it seems all samples are about the same.

I've noticed they all have the same issues, so I've reported about them :

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203114
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203115
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203113
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203654

Now I try various ways to investigate and fix the issues, but I still fail to do so.

### The question

Is there any way to deal with those issues? What should be the correct code to use bottom sheets using the support library?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**
Link to the [full answer](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) in where you can find all the explanation about how to get full behaviors like Google Maps.

---

Helping you with what you want

> what I wanted, which is the 3-phases I've done before

Using Support Library 23.x+ you can do it modifying default `BottomSheetBehavior` adding one more stat with following steps:

1. Create a Java class and extend it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>`
2. Copy paste code from default `BottomSheetBehavior` file to your new one.
3. Modify the method `clampViewPositionVertical`:
4. Add a new state

   public static final int STATE_ANCHOR_POINT = X;
5. Modify the next methods: `onLayoutChild`, `onStopNestedScroll`, `BottomSheetBehavior<V> from(V view)` and `setState` (optional)

So now you have those states:
STATE_HIDDEN
STATE_COLLAPSED
STATE_DRAGGING
STATE_ANCHOR_POINT
STATE_EXPANDED.

You can use `setBottomSheetCallback` like you do in original `BottomSheetBehavior`
The XML (without anything about parallax image like google maps) looks like:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout/>

    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout >
    </AppBarLayout >

    <NestedScrollView>
        <LinearLayout/>
    </NestedScrollView>

</CoordinatorLayout >
```

I'm going to add a [link to the example project](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) where you can find what you are looking for

**And here is how its looks like:**
[[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/rey5137/material). As far as I have seen there is no issue with this library.

Comment: According to the screenshots, the bottom sheet of the library is in "dialogs" category. Do they have a non-dialog-based bottom-sheet too? If not, it won't work well for my case, as I want to still support touching outside of the bottom sheet.

Comment: Yes, the bottom sheets in this library are in dialogs category. They won't work in your case.