# How to make a toolbar expand when pulled down and gets retreat to middle position which is exactly as describe in given video?

Tags: android, animation, view, transition

the collapsing toolbar must expand to full screen when pulled down and must scroll back to intermediate position when pulled up (even slightly). and it must act normal when scrolled up as toolbar does.

i want to learn making ui like video in link given below 
please help what should i learn and do in order to achieve this ui:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14wNBitoI33MUhWM05FYTZ2czQ

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: see collapase layout and you can add custom design with collapse layout

Comment: just see the video. its not a simple one. Atleast for me. i am beginner. help me with this. down voting won't help thats for sure.

Comment: give me the app link you used in the video

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trulia.android&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this [CollapsingToolbar](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)
It is available in Google Support Design Repositries

**UPDATE:**
Check this: [Answer By MiguelHincapieC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971546/how-to-handle-issues-of-the-new-bottom-sheet-of-the-support-design-library/37443680#37443680)
Library: [CustomBottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)

Comment: if i use collapsing toolbar the i can't use stickyscrollview in nested scrollview. then the view sticked to the bottom won't happen, so how do i pulldown action bar or collapsing toobar with gestures and expand

Comment: Explain everything in the question what u want to achieve not step by step

Comment: and u can still use stickyscrollview with CollapsingToolbar

Comment: You will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971546/how-to-handle-issues-of-the-new-bottom-sheet-of-the-support-design-library/37443680#37443680