# Can we have pictures representing places on HERE map android

Tags: android, here-api

I am working with HERE Map offline on Android, wondering if we can have real pictures for places to be shown in some view on selecting some known point on the map fragment.
Something like the screen shot attached.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mimic Google Maps' bottom-sheet 3 phases behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160423/how-to-mimic-google-maps-bottom-sheet-3-phases-behavior)

Comment: No, I checked your reference and it is not a duplicate as I already mentioned it is specifically for HERE maps and the data required is from their offline feature.
Also, I don't need a answer for creating the View, need help with Here map android sdk

Answer (score 1):

The maps data does not contain any visual images of POIs, so if you are asking whether there are any images of locations, that would be no.

However, you can bundle assets yourself in the application and match it against any results returned by the HERE SDK.

Comment: Thank you @David, will look in complementing options

Comment: Hi, I am actually having the same issue, how to get the photos of a place? and what you exactly mean by "bundle assets"? from where?